# How to save opened word document in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to make a word add-in that saves opened documents. I put a ribbon and button on it. Below is the [button click handler] code I use for saving a word document in a specific location:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ThisApplication As Word.Application
        ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("C:\email")
        ThisApplication.Quit()
        ThisApplication= Nothing
        End Sub
```

But when I click on this button, I create email.doc but that document does not contain any content of the opened document; it just creates a new doc file.

What I am doing wrong? The event-handler on this button needs to behave the same as the event-handler on the standard Word save button, so how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I can only imagine that maybe you need to create an object to represent the document itself first.  Try the following:

```
Dim ThisApplication As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument
oDoc.SaveAs("C:\email")
oDoc.Close()        
ThisApplication.Quit()
oDoc = Nothing
ThisApplication = Nothing
```